# ASP.NET MVC 4 how to implement Oauth with custom membershipprovider and roleprovider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, security

After alot of searching and alot of trying I finnaly figuered out how to let people register and login on my site (and give them role etc and do authorization). I Inherited from the class ExtendedMembershipProvider and RoleProvider, made both for them a customclass, but now I am still having issues getting Oauth to work (mainly OpenID). I registered GoogleClient in the AuthConfig, but once I try to login and it comes to the line (In AccountController.cs):

```
    if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
```

Then it says not yet implemented, now I checked extended membership and I can t override Login (since it isn t there, but where is it). I also searched google alot but no luck, any instructions for getting oauth to work with would be sweat(I think I need to make a 3th CustomOathprovider, but I am not able to find what to inherith from)!

PS: I made a custommembershiprpovder and customroleprovider because I want to use a diffrent Database scheme.

Maxim

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had to override 3 more methods in my custom memberbershipprovider

```
public override void CreateOrUpdateOAuthAccount(string provider, string providerUserId, string userName)

public override int GetUserIdFromOAuth(string provider, string providerUserId)
//return -1 if User got no OauthAccount

public override string GetUserNameFromId(int userId)
```

now it is working. (I figuered this out by overriding all methods in the membership provider, and then setting a breakpoint on each, and everywhere it went I filled in the method based on my custom Database.

Comment: I have the same problem, but dont understand how to configure OAuthWebSecurity, may you share any manual or other?

Answer (score 3):

This would be a comment if I had enough reputation to comment.

This is not how to make OAuth work in your scenario, but in case it helps, the source for OAuthWebSecurity.Login is at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5cb74eb3b2f3#src/Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth/OAuthWebSecurity.cs and to see how SimpleMembership implemented OAuth you can look at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5cb74eb3b2f3#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs.

Your project sounds cool, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the thing is I got it all fixed by overriding 3 more methods in my membershipprovider.